# How to make a failing pipe in a local variable assignment fail the function?

Tags: bash

This code:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -euo pipefail # strict mode

fn() {
        local out=$(echo hello && false)
        echo "out=$out"
}

fn
```

doesn't stop when the pipe `echo hello && false` fails. But when `local` is removed - it does stop. bash is used.

Why does the fact that this variable is local matter for error handling?
How to make it fail with a local variable assignment as it is written?

Comment: (1) "bash is used" – The shebang disagrees. (2) I'm not answering "why?", so just a comment. My answer to "how to?" is: `local out` and then separately `out=…`.

Comment: `$(...)` is a command substitution and `...&&...` is a list; neither is a pipe and `pipefail` has no effect on either. In `var=$(subst)` the outer command is the assignment which does not set exit status, so the status of `subst` is used and since it is an error and `-e` is on the function aborts.  In `local var=$(subst)` the outer command is a _declaration_ and it is successful regardless of whether `subst` is successful. To have it fail, use two _separate_ commands: `local x; x=$(subst)`. ...

Comment: ... Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490460/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844028/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524623/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913988/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157938/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844028/ and similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689805/